# Problem Of Pumping Rubber

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

One can work out by either lifting weights or using a tension band, which is like a big rubber band. If we model the rubber band as a big spring with spring constant $400 N/M$ how far in meters must I stretch the the band so it applies a force equivalent to the gravitational force on a $10kg$ weight?

Answer (score 2):

Well if you look at the value of the spring constant, it pretty much says 400 Newtons of force per meter of extension. To get how much force a 10kg mass exerts on the earth, you have to multiply this mass by the acceleration due to gravity, which is $\approx 9.8N/kg$. This is an equivalent form of units as the more commonly encountered $9.8m/s^2$. Hope this helps.